# What's the algorithm of finding the convex combination of permutation matrices for a doubly stochastic matrix?

Tags: matrices, polytopes, stochastic-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes, permutation-matrices

According to Birkhoff, $n$-by-$n$ stochastic matrices form a convex polytope whose extreme points are precisely the permutation matrices. It implies that any doubly stochastic matrix can be written as a convex combination of finitely many permutation matrices. Given a doubly stochastic matrix, is there an algorithm to compute the coefficients of a convex combination?

For example, given

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5&0.2&0.3\\ 0.1&0.6&0.3\\ 0.4&0.2&0.4\end{bmatrix},$$

how do you know the following?

$$A=0.4\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]+0.2\left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right]+0.1\left[\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right]+0.1\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right]+0.2\left[\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Please do briefly prove the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: There's always the brute force way: (1) Find some permutation matrix $P_\pi$ such that none of the entries $A[i,\pi(i)]$ are zero. (2) Subtract $\min_i A[i,\pi(i)] P_\pi$ from A. (3) Repeat until you're left with the 0 matrix.

Comment: Yes, you're right. To prove the correctness, simply notice that (1) Each time you are guaranteed to get one more zero entry; (2) Each time you're left with a multiple of a doubly stochastic matrix; (3) For any doubly stochastic matrix, $\exists \pi$ such that none of the entries $A[i,\pi(i)]$ are zero. (1) and (2) are obvious, how do you prove (3)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm expanding my comment to an answer.

You can always do it the brute force way.

1. Find some permutation matrix $P_\pi$ such that none of the entries $A[i,\pi(i)]$ are $0$.
2. Subtract $(\min_i A[i,\pi(i)])\, P_\pi$ from $A$.
3. Repeat steps (1) and (2) until you're left with the $0$ matrix.

As the OP comments, to prove that it terminates, you can note that each time you are left with a multiple of a double stochastic matrix, and step (2) always adds at least one more zero entry.

We still need to show that step (1) is always possible. This follows from [Hall's marriage theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). This theorem states that such a permutation $\pi$ exists unless there is a set $R$ of rows and a set $C$ of columns such that $|R|+|C| < n$ and $A[i,j] = 0$ unless $i \in R$ or $j \in C$. In other words, all the non-zero entries are either in a row in $C$ or a column in $R$.

We will show by contradiction that such a matrix cannot be doubly stochastic. Look at the the sum of all elements $A[i,j]$ with $i \in R$ and $j \in \bar{C}$. Since each of the column sums is $1$, 
$$\sum_{i\in R, j\in \bar{C}} A[i,j] = \sum_{j\in \bar{C}} A[i,j] = |\bar{C}|.$$ Also, each of the row sums is $1$, so
$$\sum_{i\in R, j\in \bar{C}} A[i,j] \leq \sum_{i\in R} A[i,j] = |R|.$$ 
But $|R| < |\bar{C}|$, so
$$\sum_{i\in R, j\in \bar{C}} A[i,j]\leq |R| < |\bar{C}|= \sum_{i\in R, j\in \bar{C}} A[i,j],$$
a contradiction.

Note that this gives a proof of Birkhoff's theorem. To turn it into a real algorithm, you still need an algorithm for step (1) that finds a permutation in Hall's marriage theorem. There are lots of algorithms to do this; I don't know which is the simplest one.  (It's a special case of the bipartite maximum matching problem, which in turn is a special case of the assignment problem, so any bipartite maximum matching algorithm, or any algorithm solving the assignment problem, will work.).

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients can be computed using the [Birkhoff-Von-Neumann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_algorithm). The algorithm is guaranteed to have support on less than $n^2-2n+2$ permutation matrices [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_algorithm).

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_algorithm) Johnson, Diane M.; Dulmage, A. L.; Mendelsohn, N. S. (1960-09-01). "On an Algorithm of G. Birkhoff Concerning Doubly Stochastic Matrices". Canadian Mathematical Bulletin.